# Toy program = Calendar which counts your days until birthday - Loop not working correctly

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I am just getting into java and building myself a simple toy program, which tells you when your Birthday is based on current date and also shows you simple calendar. However. I seem to be stuck in the "case 1" loop, which does not work correctly. Case 2 for same month works correctly, case 1 for some reason works only for August and months after that do not calculate correctly. Case 3 for another year is not implemented yet.

Someone help please, been on it for 4 hours and can't figure it out why it does not work.

```
public static int today;
public static int ThisMonth;
public static int MonthSwitch;
public static int DaysUntilBD;


public static void main (String args[]){
    GregorianCalendar d = new GregorianCalendar(); 

    ThisMonth = d.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    ThisMonth++;
    today = d.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


    String MonthofBirth = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Month of birth");
    int month = Integer.parseInt(MonthofBirth);
    String DayOfBirth = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Day of Birth");
    int birth = Integer.parseInt(DayOfBirth);

    d.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    int CurrentDay = d.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int CurrentMonth = d.get(Calendar.MONTH);

    //switches
    if(month > ThisMonth) MonthSwitch=1; //same year, month in future
    if(month == ThisMonth) MonthSwitch=2; //same month
    if(month < ThisMonth) MonthSwitch = 3; //birthday next year, not implemented yet


    switch(MonthSwitch) {
    case 1:
        month++;
        while(month!=ThisMonth)
        {
            System.out.println(ThisMonth);
            DaysUntilBD++;        
            d.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            ThisMonth=d.get(Calendar.MONTH);

            int CheckDay = d.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            int CheckMonth= d.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
            if (CheckDay <=7 && CheckMonth !=1) d.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        }
        today=d.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        while (birth<today){
            DaysUntilBD++;        
            d.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            today=d.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        }
        break;    

    case 2:
        while(birth!=today)
        {
            DaysUntilBD++;        
            d.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            today=d.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        }
        break;

    }

    month=month-1;  
    d.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    d.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);
    int DayOfTheWeek = d.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);


    for (int i = Calendar.SUNDAY; i < DayOfTheWeek; i++ )
        System.out.print("  ");

    do {
        int day = d.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        if(day<10) System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print(day);

        if (day == birth) System.out.print("*");

        else System.out.print(" ");

        if (DayOfTheWeek == Calendar.SUNDAY)
            System.out.println();

        d.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        DayOfTheWeek = d.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    } while (d.get(Calendar.MONTH) == month);

    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("Your birthdays are in "+ DaysUntilBD);
    System.out.print(" days");

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that once you've entered into `case 1`, you start a `while` loop. The condition to get out of the loop is that `month!=ThisMonth`, but neither of them change inside the loop, they remain contsant all the time, so the loop is infinite.
You should change `month` inside the loop, and not before it (like `month++` before the `while`).
And as @ControlAltDel said - there are better options to compare dates, but it's a good exercise for learning purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR. This will make it much easier

The pseudo-code below is almost what you want; you need to still account for leap years.

```
Calendar today = ...;
Calendar futureDate = ...;

int days = (today.get(YEAR) - futureDate(YEAR)) * 365;
days = days + futureDate.get(DAY_OF_YEAR) - today.get(DAY_OF_YEAR);
```